# Can I find out my overall or per-champion win/loss ratio?

Tags: league-of-legends

The only relevant stats I've been able to find are the total wins. Do the other stats exist somewhere I haven't looked yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only shows it for ranked stats but if you want to see your overall stats try using http://www.lolstatistics.com although it doesn't show your personal champion stats it does show your overall k.d champion kills sperate to turrets but also shows how many netural monsters youve killed its nice for tracking your gameplay and seeing area's your a bit weaker on

Comment: I was not aware of that site. Lots of cool info on there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you play Ranked Games, you will have access to a bevy of information that includes per champion % win rate, average K/D/A with each champion, total number of multi-kills and kill streaks, etc.

Before season 1, this was available for normal games as well, but post the start of season 1, the functionality has been limited to Ranked Games.

Comment: That's interesting. Any idea what the rational was for removing it?

Comment: @Dave - I think it was probably oversight on Riot's part; i.e., they though the folks who cared about stats would be playing Ranked games in the first place, so we don't need to keep track of normal games anymore.

Comment: It could also be a result of the huge increase in popularity of the game and storage issues. To save everyone's per champs stats probably takes up a lot more room than just the ranked stats.